# jQuery Slide Toggle menu cookie issue

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I have created a slideToggle dropdown menu in WordPress. I have just uploaded my code into JSFiddle. You can see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/pgtksr02/5/).

I want to keep the toggle menu open on all sub menus it has. I am trying using cookies.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open') {
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
    }

    $('.fixed-navbar').on('click', '.dropdown', function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
            } else {
                $.cookie('panel', 'open');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie plugin.

For some reason it's not working.

Comment: Try `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: why are you using cookie for this tiny job :o use addClass and removeClass that will work for you. see documentation of addClass and removeClass

Comment: Cookies are the wrong way of going about this. You should also edit your question and provide the relevant HTML as a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just doing what danish443 suggested?

Try with:

```
var $menu_with_children = $('.menu-item-has-children > a');

$menu_with_children.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').hasClass('visible')) {
        $this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').addClass('visible').slideDown('slow');
    } else{
        $this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').removeClass('visible').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

And css

```
ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

You can add this

```
$('#menu-main-menu li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('> .sub-menu').length) {
        $(this).find('> a').append('+');
    }
});
```

And instead of + put the arrow down icon, so that you can see what menu can be expanded.

Comment: I have tested this code. Unfortunately the toggle works just like my orginial code. The real issue is I want to keep the `.dropdown-menu` opened on each sub pages on click. It is collapsed when open new sub page and when refresh a page.

Comment: Yeah, this code will toggle the collapse, not remember it.